# iOS SDK: Two TextViews in one ScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

Is it possible to put two TextViews in one ScrollView, so that only the ScrollView scrolls and the two embedded TextViews can't scroll independently? (But if the ScrollView scrolls the TextViews should scroll either so that the rest of the text is shown.)

Thx. Regards, Daniel

Edit:

Current code http://www.muehlbachler.org/spt.zip

Declaration of what I need and what the app does so far:
One part (the just needed one) is a simple port checker which checks a range of ports if they are open or rejected by a host. For that there are two main sections below the form called "open ports" and "closed ports". Under each main section are two textviews where the ports are displayed (either they are open or closed). I made two textviews because it is a better experience if you want to see all open/closed ports because then you must not scroll so often.
The problem now is that each textview can scroll independently but that's abit nasty because I just want to scroll the open/closed ports textviews together. In fact, two of the textviews must be grouped together so that they can only scroll together.
An example: imagine you have 100 closed ports and they are now displayed divided into two textviews (50 : 50). Now you want to take a quick look at all closed port numbers and (now) you have to scroll two times because you have to scroll textview1 and textview2 separately. Now the wished behaviour comes in: you just want to scroll one time and if you scroll that time you want to see all closed ports (because the two separate textviews are scrolled either).
My idea was that I simply put a scrollview before the textviews and then I can scroll them together, but that doesn't work... :(

Edit:

Image added. I'm not allowed to add immages due to my reputation, so I uploaded it: http://www.muehlbachler.org/spt.jpg

Comment: means when u scroll ...the textViews should not scroll independently...am I correct?

Comment: okay...now tell me are u using xib for this?

Comment: yep, I added the parts to the xib and connected it with IBOutlets so that I can use them in my class.

Comment: okay daniel now...place your scrollview before your textViews in xib

Comment: ok, so now it is: scrollview -> 2 textviews

Comment: but the needed behaviour doesn't exiist too. The textviews are scrolling independently but the scrollview doesn't.

Comment: Daniel I request you to edit your question with elaboration...I am not able to comprehend the problem yet :(

Comment: ok, I uploaded the project and wrote a short declaration what I need.

Comment: @Daniel M. by looking at the screenshot your requirement can be easily done using UITableView. How about a custom Cell?

Comment: ok, that was my first thought too, but how can I embedd a table view in a normal view and how can I access the values of the cells?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a slightly different tack in trying to keep two text views scroll position synchronized. I would make the overall view's `UIViewController` a `UIScrollViewDelegate`. I would implement a `scrollViewDidScroll:` method that would ask the just scrolled text view where it scrolled to and then tell the other text view to scroll to the same position. To prevent a loop where this method keeps repeating I'd set a flag to check before sending the scroll message. This is very easy if both text views are guaranteed to be the same size, but may need more work if they are different sizes. Maybe the scroll position would be calculated on percentages. Maybe the scroll views need to know about content, and scroll to specific headings.

Additional methods in the `UIScrollViewDelegate` could be implemented to keep synchronization during user scrolling, depending upon how I wanted the scrolling text views to act.

In response to comments:

It sounds like the percentage calculation would work best in this situation. Each scroll view has `contentSize` and `contentOffset` properties. The other view's offset can be calculated with  `(thisView.contentOffset.x/thisView.contentSize.height) * otherView.contentSize.height`.

I was thinking the flag may be necessary if calling setContentOffset:animated: on the other scroll would trigger another call to the delegate's `scrollViewDidScroll:` method. Checking the flag could stop the loop. If the flag is set, don't tell the other scroll view to move, because this is a reactionary `scrollViewDidScroll`.

`scrollViewDidScroll:` is called every time the scroll view needs to be redrawn. So in one user interaction this method may be called hundreds of times. This alone would be able to keep the two scroll views in sync.

Comment: OK, I just added a short description of the problem to my question above. So in fact the content is not equal because it could be that there are 20 lines in one view and about 22 lines in the other.
what do you mean with setting a flag?

Comment: wouldn't that just scroll the second textview when the first texview has finished scrolling? the problem then is mentioned above because the scrolling of the second is not as slowly as the first one.

Comment: wow, now they are nearly synchronous... but the other textview which gets scrolles automatically has some lags and how do I manage the percentage calculation because the second textview is 2 lines longer (every time!)?

Answer (score 0):

why need two textView inside scrollview then why not use only textview it has scrollview embeded to see the rest of text just scroll the textview.

Comment: jep, but now I have two textviews where port numbers get displayed. I need two textvews because I want to divide the ports so that I mustn't scroll so much. The problem now is that I can scroll each textview independently but I need the behaviour that both textviews should scroll together (but not independently). In fact, I thought a scrollview should be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: @Daniel M. how about using a UITableview with two sections?

Comment: Ok, but never worked with an embedded tableview... Imagine the following (iPad app):
at the top textfields for hostname, port range and button to proceed the port check. below that there are two "main sections" called "Open ports" and "Closed ports". Below that headers are two textviews for displaying the ports (two textviews for each main section). In fact I have four textviews where two textviews should get connected together for better experience. Additionally, the textviews gets updated really often (asynchronous port checks).

Comment: @Daniel M please post a screenshot so that everybody can better understand what actually you want to do.

Comment: added image link because I am not allowed to add images directly. I hope it is clear.